# Can a finite group admit a partial order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was trying to come with some examples of partially ordered finite groups, but I had no success, so I was wondering, if some finite group can admit a partial order and if not, then why?

Comment: You can order any finite set any way you like.  However, if you want the partial order to respect the group operation, you will run into problems.  Technically, every group admits the trivial partial order (where no two elements are comparable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As vadim123 mentioned in his comment, there is always a trivial order. Suppose you have some non-trivial order that respects the group structure on your group $G$. Suppose $g\in G$ and $1\leq g$. Then multiplying by $g$ you will get $g\leq g^2$, $g^2\leq g^3$ et.c. But since $G$ is finite, eventually $g^n=1$ for some $n$. Then you have $1\leq g\leq g^2\leq \dots\leq g^n=1$. Therefore, in your order all $g^i$ should be equal. So you can't have a non-trivial order respecting the group structure.

Comment: The initial assumption might not sound generic, but if $g \leq h$ then $1 \leq g^{-1} h$. In other words, if the partial order respects left (or right) multiplication, then the only comparable elements are $g \leq g$.